# Can a sequence simplified to one number?

Tags: algorithms

**Is there any algorithm there can convert any (non-infinity) sequence into one number (and back again with one solution)?**

Of course can it be turned into a N-base number (N=max(sequence)+1) but it require the highest number in the sequence which have multiple solutions.

**Thank you.**

*Sorry for my bad english*

Comment: only positive integer sequences? or...? this question seems like nonsense without being more precise

Comment: @oldrinb The question is not very well-written, but the example makes it very clear what is asked.

Comment: Godel numbering are going to come up some time soon...I don't know much details about it though, but I'm pretty sure it is for precisely this kind of question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest continued fractions.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction

For example, if your sequence is $1,2,3,\dots$, it would become

$$\dfrac1{1+\dfrac1{2+\dfrac1{3+\dfrac1{4+\dots}}}}=0.69777465796400798201\dots.$$

See [Wolfram Alpha calculation.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=N%5BFromContinuedFraction%5B%7B0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17%7D%5D,20%5D)
And the [reverse calculation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ContinuedFraction%5b0.69777465796400798201%5d) to recover the sequence.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, you can always string the sequence together. You just need a special character to act as a delimiter. This can be taken care of by using bases, as you suggest.

Here is an algorithm for converting a sequence into a number:

1. Assume that the sequence $a_1, ... ,a_n$ is given in base 9.
2. Write $$N = a_1.9.a_2.9. a_3 ...  9.a_n . $$
   Here "." means just putting the digits one after the other. $N$ should be interpreted as a number in base 10.

To convert a number into a sequence, just take $a_1$ to be all the digits until the first $9$, take $a_2$ to be the digits between the first $9$ and the second $9$, and so on. The elements of the sequence should be interpreted as numbers in base 9, of course.